# calling python from golang

Tags: python, go, gcc, cython

I am following https://poweruser.blog/embedding-python-in-go-338c0399f3d5 example on using python code from a golang application. I installed the python3.8 dev. When I try go build
I get

"undefined reference to Py_Finalize" any idea why?  I have set the export PKG_CONFIG_PATH= to where my python3.pc file is.

```
package main
  
 // #cgo pkg-config: python3
  // #include <Python.h>
  import "C"
 
  import (
    "unsafe"
  )
 
 func main() {

   pycodeGo := `
 import sys
 for path in sys.path:
   print(path)
 ` 
   
   defer C.Py_Finalize()
   C.Py_Initialize()
   pycodeC := C.CString(pycodeGo)
   defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(pycodeC))
   C.PyRun_SimpleString(pycodeC)
 
 }
```

Comment: Hello! Could you clarify why you included the tags `gcc` and `cython`? This question doesn't appear to be about either of them.

Answer (score 4):

I was running into the same problem. It turns out my `python.pc` file was not providing all of the necessary flags, namely `-lpython3.8` in the `Libs` section.

Here is an example of the `python3.pc` file automatically generated:

```
# See: man pkg-config
prefix=/your/dir/path
exec_prefix=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: Python
Description: Build a C extension for Python
Requires:
Version: 3.8
Libs.private: -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
Libs:
Cflags: -I${includedir}/python3.8 -I${includedir}/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/python3.8
```

I made a custom `python3.pc` file in my local directory and changed the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable to reference the new file.

Here is an example of the new file:

```
prefix=/your/dir/path
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: GoPython
Description: Embed a python interpreter into go
Requires:
Version: 3.8
Libs.private: -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
Libs: -lpython3.8
Cflags: -I${includedir}/python3.8
```

Then by simply running `go build` your Go file should compile.